# DAX Measure should refer to different filter options

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax

This are the tables: Relation through BusinessUnitID between Business Unit and Table 1

```
BusinessUnit            Table1                  Table2

BusinessUnitID          BusinessUnitID          Indicator2
BusinessUnitCode        Quantity            
                        Semester            
                        Season          
                        Indicator1
```

i´m new here and need your help. I have following DAX Measure:

```
    CALCULATE([Quantity];
ALL('Table2'[Indicator2]);
FILTER(ALL(Table1[Season];Table1[Semester]);
IF(ISFILTERED(Table1[Season];Table1[Season];MAX(Table1[Season])-100;
IF(ISFILTERED(Table1[Semester];Table1[Semester];MAX(Table1[Semester])-10));
FILTER(ALL(Table1);Table1[Indicator1]<=MAX('Table2'[Indicator2])+2))
```

My Problem is that this measure doesn´t change if i want to filter with different dimensions in Table1. Do i have to add something to the query?

This is the result:

```
Business Unit   Unit1

        Quantity
20132   39.477
20141   2.751.428
20142   66.282.756
20151   77.415.932
20152   76.600.664
20161   82.558.674
20162   411.104.765
20171   437.293.327
20172   444.460.709
20181   457.535.523
Total   457.535.523
```

As you can see i want to filter Business Unit for this measure. But it doesn´t react on this filter no matter what is selected. Business Unit is in Table1. Beside that: How can i have the total over all Half year?

Comment: Weclime to SO! It might be easier if you show a little reproducible example.

Comment: I meant example we could re-create. Simple tables and measures enough to demonstrate your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: i´ve added table structure above. there´s no connection between table1 and table2. Are this informations enough? My main problem is that measure is not reacting to selections for Business Unit.

Comment: I get the following errors: `Too many arguments were passed to the FILTER function. The maximum argument count for the function is 2.` & `Too many arguments were passed to the ISFILTERED function. The maximum argument count for the function is 1.`

Comment: What do you want your measure to calculate?

Comment: oh. can you please try this: CALCULATE([Quantity];
ALL('Table2'[Indicator2]);
FILTER(ALL(Table1[Season];Table1[Semester]);
IF(ISFILTERED(Table1[Season];Table1[Season];MAX(Table1[Season])-100;
IF(ISFILTERED(Table1[Semester];Table1[Semester];MAX(Table1[Semester])-10;
Table1[Season];MAX(Table1[Season])-100)));
FILTER(ALL(Table1);Table1[Indicator1]<=MAX('Table2'[Indicator2])+2))

Comment: Still errors for me unfortunately, again FILTER with >2 args and ISFILTERED with >1 args. Can you tell what you want it to calculate?

Comment: it should calculate quantity based whether if semester or season selected. That´s why i put in the if isfiltered function. Beside that it should filter the indicator1 which should be smaller than indicator2. The ALL function is to remove the filtering on indicator2.

Comment: I think you're missing a closing parenthesis for the `ISFILTERED` functions

Comment: But why is the measure not reacting on "Business Unit". This is my main question? Is it because of FILTER(ALL(Table1[Season];Table1[Semester]);?

Comment: I think it is because 'ALL(Table1)'

Comment: Hi thank you. I have commented FILTER(ALL(Table1);Table1[Indicator1]<=MAX('Table2'[Indicator2])+2)) out and it worked. But i need to implement this filter option Table1[Indicator1]<=MAX('Table2'[Indicator2])+2. How can i do it without filtering ALL?